# EF Core creates FKs when Property is [NotMapped] but another Property is named RelationID

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following class in the `DbContext`

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // [...] More Properties
    [NotMapped]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

the `Customer` class was not in the database and mapped manually by `Activity.CustomerID`

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // [...] More Properties

    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

Now i can added `Customer` to the `DbContext` and created a Migration.
The Migration adds FKs between `Activity.CustomerID` and `Customer.ID`. That is preventing me from applying the migration, as the existing data is referencing to IDs that are not yet in the Customers table.

What is the way to prevent EF to create these FKs?
I want to have them in a later stage when the Customers Table is filled.

Error when applying migration:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Activity_Customers_CustomerID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-supii-4DAAEDA2-0208-4652-AFF2-EE02C7F6A353", table "dbo.Customers", column 'ID'.
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to migrate changes if you have already done so `manually`. Migration is needed to ensure your current **business state**  is up to date with your databases. So, if you changed DB manually, you can already use it, but your entities should correspond to the changes.

Comment: Remove `public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }` from `Customer` (or maybe marking it as `NotMapped` also will work). Since you have no FK, you don't have relation, so EF should not (can not) fill non-related entities automatically.